# Missing some more adjustments to make routing work in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Following this http://laravel.com/docs/quick#routing

I add this:

```
Route::get('users', function()
{
    return 'Users!';
});
```

to the bottom of /app/routes.php and GET it from my browser `http://localhost/users`. But the returned result is `users Not Found`.

I've also tried a route of `/users` too, and this does the same.

Comment: What is your Web Server? What is the base URL of your app? Is it possible that your app is running in subdirectory of localhost? Wamp for example creates directories. Then your URL should be http://localhost/<app>/users

Comment: Do you have any other routes in the file which could be conflicting?

Comment: @CarlMarkham a solid error should appear then or at least one of them will work.

Comment: I didn't set up any baseURL, if I use the default route
`Route::get('/', function()
{
 return View::make('hello');
});`
Everything works fine

Comment: @CarlMarkham I don't have any other routes in the file

Comment: @user3431664, make an aswer of yourself and accept (it will require some more time) it in order to close the question as resovled.

Comment: Should the route be `/users` rather than `users`?

Comment: No @halfer it won't work either. Is this a myth ?

Comment: The inexplicable failure

Comment: Why not try debugging the routing table? I don't know Laravel, but it is sure to be amenable to adding debug messages in the "add route" and "lookup route" phases.

Comment: Thank you @halfer I found it

Answer (score 1):

Oh no, the route should be:

```
http://localhost/index.php/users
```

That should work.

Comment: The fact that you have to use `index.php` in your URL indicates that URL rewriting is not configured correctly on your server. See http://laravel.com/docs/installation#pretty-urls

Comment: I suspect that if you'd mentioned that "users Not Found" was an Apache 404 then you'd have received an answer straight away! Glad you found it though.

Comment: No @Kryten, it is not about the htaccess file, I just didn't turn AllowOverride All on in apache config file. Thank you two a lot